# Showing and disposing tooltip .NET

Tags: c#, .net, tooltip, yfiles

I am working with yFiles.Net component which I use for representing dependencies between objects in some SQL database (graph representation).

I need to create tooltip which will appear when I point cursors on some object. That tooltip not contains just text, it contains images also. I know how to make custom class which extends default Tooltip class and then to override methods for drawing custom tooltips.

What i do not know is how to show tooltip when I point on some object on graph, and how to dispose it when I move cursor from object on graph? Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: Just one note, as long as you are evaluating yFiles you are entitled to free support by yWorks. While some of us are frequenting Stack Overflow as well, it remains not the preferred way of doing support (mostly because yFiles is a lot smaller than other libraries people ask about and so yFiles questions tend to remain unanswered here a lot of times). Nothing wrong with asking here, but know that it might not be as helpful as asking our support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 private CustomTooltip m_tooltip;
 private MouseHoverInputMode m_mouseHoverMode;

 private void SetupToolTips(GraphEditorInputMode mode)
    {

        m_tooltip = new CustomTooltip(m_model.TooltipImages);

        ItemHoverInputMode itemHoverMode = new ItemHoverInputMode();
        itemHoverMode.HoverItems = GraphItemTypes.Node | GraphItemTypes.Edge;
        mode.ItemHoverInputMode = itemHoverMode;

        m_mouseHoverMode = new MouseHoverInputMode(m_tooltip, textProvider);
        mode.MouseHoverInputMode = m_mouseHoverMode;
        mode.ItemHoverInputMode.HoveredItemChanged += new EventHandler<HoveredItemChangedEventArgs>(ToolTipEvent);
    }

    private void ToolTipEvent(object sender, HoveredItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        m_tooltip.Item = e.Item; 
    }

    private void textProvider(object sender, ToolTipQueryEventArgs e)
    {
        if (m_tooltip.Item is INode || m_tooltip.Item is IEdge)
        {
            e.ToolTip = " ";
        }
    }

 public class CustomTooltip : ToolTip
  {
    private void OnPopup(object sender, PopupEventArgs e)
     {
     }
    private void OnDraw(object sender, DrawToolTipEventArgs e)
     {
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to intercept the 
[`ItemHoverInputMode.HoveredItemChanged Event`](http://docs.yworks.com/yfilesdotnet/html/T_yWorks_yFiles_UI_Input_ItemHoverInputMode.htm).

I have not tested this nor worked with yFiles before, but according to [documentation](http://docs.yworks.com/yfilesdotnet/developers-guide/mvc_controller.html#cls_GraphViewerInputMode_events) this should work:

```
// 'gc' is of type yWorks.yFiles.UI.GraphControl.  

var ihim = new ItemHoverInputMode(); 
ihim.HoveredItemChanged += YourEvenHandler;
gc.InputModes.Add(ihim);
```

Then check the element in the event handler and display or hide the tooltip.

Comment: I used exactly that way before posting question but it didn't worked for me. I believe that the answer is in using MouseHoverInputMode

Comment: If you already tried it, you might want to include this information in your question and further explain what the issue was with this approach. I.e. "What did you expect? And what was the actual behavior?"

Comment: Yes that is my bad, I should include that information in my question. I expected to tooltip be shown when I hover object, and it shows tooltip only when i click object. I believe that event HoveredItemChanged is called only when some hovered item is changed (clicked).

Comment: I think your question would benefit from a code snippet that shows this unexpected behaviour.

Comment: [```GraphViewerInputMode.QueryItemToolTip Event```](http://docs.yworks.com/yfilesdotnet/html/E_yWorks_yFiles_UI_Input_GraphViewerInputMode_QueryItemToolTip.htm) could be the event you're looking for then.

Comment: That is event for showing text tooltips, like I sad i question I need to show tooltips which contains images also.

Comment: @Essien: From your support e-mail it appears that you have found a way of doing so. You can just set your custom tooltip on MouseHoverInputMode and it will show that one. I also didn't quite understand why ItemHoverInputMode was not sufficient for showing a tooltip yourself and disposing it at the right time again. Your belief regarding ItemHoverInputMode having to do anything with clicks is definitely wrong, e.g. the highlight in [this demo](http://live.yworks.com/yfiles-for-html/2.0/view/graphviewer/index.html) has been created using exactly that input mode, and no clicks are needed.

Comment: That's right i found solution using MouseHoverInputMode, and i will post solution as soon as I can.